# Use of undefined constant Panel_Controller - assumed 'Panel_Controller

Tags: codeigniter, web-hosting

Uploading Application built in `Codeigniter` I am facing error that

> "Use of undefined constant Panel_Controller - assumed
>   'Panel_Controller"

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('javascript');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->load->library('email');
      $this->load->library('session');

      if($this->session->userdata('id'))
      {
            return redirect(Panel_Controller);

      }
```

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Comment: use this: return redirect('Panel_Controller');

Answer (score 2):

```
First load the url helper in your construct by 
 $this->CI->load->helper('url'); 

if($this->session->userdata('id')){
   redirect('Panel_Controller');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to make a route

```
$route['dashboard'] = "Panel_Controller/index";
```

And then

```
if($this->session->userdata('id')){
   redirect('dashboard');
}
```

OR

```
if($this->session->userdata('id')){
   redirect('Panel_Controller/index', 'refresh');
}
```